# Redux Form Synchronous field level validation won't work using a complex field names?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am using Redux-Form *7.4.2* and I have a form which has field names in the following format: *textIntl[0].value*, *textIntl[1].value* etc. I am trying to set up synchronous validation for these fields, but when logging meta.error in the field it is always undefined.

For testing purposes I have hardcoded the error in the validator function which has the exact same name as the form field as the key.

When console logging errors before returning from the validator it is always.

```
{ textIntl[0].value: "UH OH" }
```

In Chrome's Redux Dev Tools I can see the syncErrors in the redux store under this form.

```
form: {
     "heading-component-editor": {
          syncErrors: {
             "textIntl[0].value": "UH OH "
          }
     }
}
```

Validator Function:

```
export const validator = (formData: Immutable.Map<string, any>): Record<string, string> => {
    const errors = {
        "textIntl[0].value": "UH OH"
    };
    return errors;
};
```

Form (Where validator gets passed):

```
<Form
     form={HEADING_EDITOR_FORM_NAME}
     onSubmit={onSubmit}
     initialValues={component}
     validate={validator}
     enableReinitialize
>
     <TextareaField
          name={`textIntl[{0].value`}
          ...
     /> 
   ...
</Form>
```

I expect meta.error to hold the string error message which is included in the key, value pair within the error object being returned from the validator, but instead it is always undefined.

Has anybody came across this issue before?